# How to test picklist controller apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, unit-test, class

I have a lightning component that works just fine but I need to test a controller:

```
    public class PickListController {

    @AuraEnabled        
    public static List<String> getPickListValuesIntoList(String objectType, String selectedField){

        List<String> pickListValuesList = new List<String>();

        Schema.SObjectType convertToObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectType);
        System.debug('convertToObj: ' + convertToObj);

        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult res = convertToObj.getDescribe();
        System.debug('res: ' + res);

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = res.fields.getMap().get(selectedField).getDescribe();
        System.debug('fieldResult: ' + fieldResult);

        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        System.debug('ple: ' + ple);

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
            pickListValuesList.add(pickListVal.getLabel() + ';' + pickListVal.getValue());
        }
        System.debug('pickListValuesList: ' + pickListValuesList);

        return pickListValuesList;
    }
}
```

I tried testing with the following code (Contact is the object and Rol__c is the multiselect picklist field):

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData = TRUE)
public class PickListControllerTest {
    static testMethod void test() { 

        List<Contact> testContact = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Rol__c from Contact Where Rol__c != null LIMIT 1];
        system.debug('The size of testContact Is: ' + testContact.size());

        List<String> result = PickListController.getPickListValuesIntoList('Contact', testContact[0].Rol__c);

    } 
}
```

But is not working fine. I always receive the following errors

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

And

```
Class.PickListController.getPickListValuesIntoList: line 14, column 1
Class.PickListControllerTest.test: line 23, column 1
```

The error is on this line:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = res.fields.getMap().get(selectedField).getDescribe();
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help? **Please!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here. Logic first:

```
    List<String> result = PickListController.getPickListValuesIntoList('Contact', testContact[0].Rol__c);
```

`testContact[0].Rol__c` is a reference to the content of the `Rol__c` field, as a string, not the name of the `Rol__c` field itself. It's passed into `getPickListValuesIntoList()` as the parameter `selectedField`, which is later used

```
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = res.fields.getMap().get(selectedField).getDescribe();
```

But here, `selectedField` is not the name of a field - it's whatever is *in* the field `Rol__c` on this Contact. Hence `get()` returns `null`, because the `Map` does not contain that value, and a `NullPointerException` ensues.

Instead, pass a literal string name of a field, such as `'Rol__c'`, to this method. Note that your test's running user must have FLS to this field or you will still get a `NullPointerException`.

You should never write new tests with `seeAllData=true`, unless you *know* that you are in one of the very small number of areas that require that annotation. Your unit tests should always create the data they require. However, in this case, you actually don't require any data, because your code under test is only accessing the org's schema. You can do away with the annotation and the query entirely.

Comment: Thx @DavidReed, you're a real apex genius. You where right, I was using `testContact[0].Rol__c` instead of  `Rol__c` (What you told me is new info for me, but I should have guessed this by myself). And I know all those things you said about testing classes, I did things this way because I was desperate :))) My other test classes are well build and now this one is too. Thx again